# FileWriter not writing to file java

Tags: java, file-io

I'm using FileWriter to write to a file in java, but it's acting weird.

```
try
{
    newFile = new File(typeOfData);
    if (!newFile.exists())
    {
        newFile.createNewFile();
        writer = new FileWriter(newFile);

        for (Map<String, Double> tfidf : tfidfs)
        {
            Set<String> keys = tfidf.keySet();
            Iterator<String> iterator = keys.iterator();

            //int i = 1;
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                String featureValue = iterator.next() + ":" + tfidf.get(iterator.next()) + " ";
                //System.out.print(featureValue);
                writer.write(featureValue);

                //i++;
            }
            writer.write("\n");
            //System.out.println();
            writer.flush();
        }
        //writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

In the while loop if, instead of `iterator.next()`, I use the variable `int i = 1` and `i++` it writes just fine, with all the values and everything. But when i use this code as it is written it just creates a blank file with nothing in it. I don't understand why this is happening. Any suggestions?

Comment: You call *iterator.next()* twice in the loop, hope you can ensure that there are an even amount of elements to iterate over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String featureValue = iterator.next() + ":" + tfidf.get(iterator.next()) + " ";
```

You just called `next()` twice, getting two keys from the `Set`. Your resulting `String featureValue` would contain the first key and the value of the second.

```
String key = iterator.next();
String featureValue = key + ":" + tfidf.get(key) + " ";
```

**Edit to add:** Then as a guess as to why you currently have no output... you have an odd number of keys and at the end, when there isn't a key left for the second `next()`, it's throwing an exception (which I'm guessing you're ignoring), you're not flushing to the file, and you get no output. If you had an even number of keys ... it actually would have "worked" and you'd just have a file with half the lines you were expecting ;)

Comment: ummmm no not really the first time i called it im getting the key.. the second time i called it im getting the value of that key

Comment: No ... you are getting *two keys from your Set*. So what you actually end up with is the first key with the value of the second in your resulting `String featureValue`.

Comment: And at the end, when there isn't a key left, it's throwing an exception (which I'm guessing you're ignoring), you're not flushing to the file, and you get no output.